# Django saving to Foreign field

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I'm trying to save an Item based on the Foreign Key Primary Key for topCategory and middleCategory.

models.py

```
class MiddleCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class TopCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    middleCategory = models.ManyToManyField(MiddleCategory)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


# Item
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, db_index=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
#     brand_id = models.IntegerField()
    retailer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=800, unique=True, default='')
    model_numbers = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)


    featured = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, default='NO')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    topCategory = models.ForeignKey(TopCategory)
    middleCategory = models.ForeignKey(MiddleCategory)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In my script I'm saving like this:

```
            Product(title=title,
                    price=price,
                    brand=brand,
                    retailer=retailer,
                    image=image, 
                    url=url,
                    description=description, 

                    midCategory=midCategory,
                    topCategory=topCategory
                    ).save()
```

This is the error I am getting:

ValueError: Cannot assign "'1'": "Product.topCategory" must be a "TopCategory" instance.

Comment: can you print what is topCategory ?

Comment: Yep, it's an integer '1'. I've checked my primary keys for TopCategory class and there is a '1'.

Comment: The error seems clear; you need the actual instance of TopCategory, not its primary key.

Comment: I've tested this in the shell too. I've tried the following:

topCategory='Computing' & topCategory=1.

Neither work.

Comment: Could this be due to the fact TopCategory has a 'ManyToMany' field?

Comment: @Jack yes, neither of those are instances of TopCategory; one is a string and the other is an integer.

Comment: Got it now, thanks to you both. Lack of understand on my part but understand the actual need of the instance now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get instance of TopCategory

```
instance = TopCategory.objects.get(id=topCategory)
```

then

```
Product(title=title,
                    price=price,
                    brand=brand,
                    retailer=retailer,
                    image=image, 
                    url=url,
                    description=description, 
                    midCategory=midCategory,
                    topCategory=instance
                    ).save()
```

Comment: Perfect, that's work and I understand what was missing now. Thanks